# R - How would I create a structure to hold data

Tags: r

I am using R, and I have some genes which have some meta data (field) such as name, type, and other data.

What I want to do is create some object or dictionary that will allow me to store the data in fields and access it via a key and access its fields. How can I do this in R?

Here is an example:

```
gene{

name = "geneName",
type = "some type",
...
...
}
```

I can access the gene as such:

```
gene <- gene("geneName")
type <- gene.type
```

Comment: You likely are looking for a list (i.e. `gene <- list(name = "geneName", type = "some type"); gene$name; # [1] "geneName"`).

Comment: Awesome thanks. Just make it an answer and I'll accept it